# How do I join an unbound Data Column at the end of the bound DataColumns in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView where I want to join an unbound Data Column, named `Total Price`.

I can add the unbound Column using the DataGridView Designer, however, when I load the bound Columns into the DataGridView, the `Total Price` column is at the left-most of the grid.

I want it to be at the right-most side of the grid.
I can't find any way to format the unbound Column in Visual Studio.

Are there ways to code the position of the column or does the Designer have a built-in function to move a Column's position?

Comment: welcome to SO! please read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and correct your question according to instruction

Comment: You can set the DisplayIndex of that Column to another value. E.g., `dataGridView1.Columns(0).DisplayIndex = dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1`. Or add it in code after you have set the DGV's DataSource, using the Add method of the Columns' collection. E.g., `DataGridView1.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewColumn() With {.Name = "Some Name", .DisplayIndex = [The Column Position]})` etc.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you!!! can you write it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Allright, I've added a few notes on this matter. If you have questions, comment on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of a Column in a DataGridView can be determined in different ways:

1. Setting the desired order in the designer.
2. Setting the [AllowUserToOrderColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoordercolumns) property to `true`, which allows to reorder the Columns by dragging them with the Mouse.
3. Adding the Columns in code, in a specific sequence.
4. Setting a Column's [DisplayIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex) property, to modify the position of a Column in the grid at run-time.
   To note: changing the `DisplayIndex` property modifies the position in the grid, **it does not change the Column's Index**.

Move an existing Column to the last position in the grid:
(the first Column will become the last one)

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
```

*As note before,* `Column[0]`, *even if shown in the last position, will still have* `index = 0`, *so, still* `Column[0]`.

Add a new Column in code and set its position in the grid:
(the new TextBoxColumn has a name, a Column Header text and occupies the first position in the grid layout)

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() {
    Name = "NewColumn",
    HeaderText = "New Column",
    DisplayIndex = 0,
});
```